# Why can't I overload a non-class function with a class function?

Tags: c++

I have two overloaded functions 'func'. func(int,int) is defined outside class and func(int) is defined inside. How can I call func(int,int) from inside the class's member functions?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int func(int a, int b)
{   return a+b;}

class test
{
    int a;

    public:
    int func(int);
    int driver();
};

int test::func(int b)
{   return b;}

int test::driver()
{   return func(10,20);}

int main()
{
    test A;
    cout<<A.driver();   //ERROR: NO MATCHING FUNCTION TO CALL FUNC(INT,INT)
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
return ::func(10,20);
```

Using `::` in front of a name means to look in the global namespace. It will then find the global `func`, not the `func` contained in the class.

EDIT:

`func` in the class isn't overloading the global `func` per se, but is *hiding* it. When lookup starts for `func` when it is called, it finds `test::func` first, even though `::func` is a better match. Changing the name or removing `test::func` will remove the first match that lookup came across, and it will proceed until it finds the next one, `::func`.

As to why it doesn't start in the global namespace, there are many reasons. I can't speak for the people who designed it, but these are all problems that would occur if it were changed.

1: Anybody writing code in a namespace would have to qualify every name with the namespace (`std::cout` vs `cout`). Failure to do so could lead to silent bugs where the wrong variables were changed, depending on what existed in the scopes above it.

2: Unqualified lookup would find functions less likely to be related to the code sooner (the function right next to where you called it is far more likely to be related to your code than the one in a different header file two namespaces above you).

3: Functions would have the opposite lookup of variables. I can't specify the scope of a local inside a function (`void func() { int i; /*no*/func::i = 0;/*no*/}`), so lookup for variables would still have to start in the enclosing scope and work outwards. It would make no sense for the two to work in opposite directions.

Comment: Can you also tell me why doesnt the compiler automatically look in the global scope? For non overloaded it does